# Expression for $\int_0^t e^{\gamma s}f'(s)$

Tags: integration

Let $f:[0,t] \to \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function. Is there some nice evaluation of the integral
$$\int_0^t e^{\gamma s}f'(s)$$
(where $\gamma$ is a constant) in terms of $f$ and the expontential function and not involving another integral? I think i want a "closed form" expression.

Comment: Do you know integration by parts?

Comment: @Paul Yes but this gives me an integral which is not wanted, of $\int_0^t \gamma e^{\gamma s}f(t)$

Comment: I want an expression without any integrals left

Comment: Not possible unless you know something about f.